# How would I restrict access to certain columns in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How could I best restrict column level access to some tables in redshift?

I want to be able to grant read access to tables but not to certain columns. If redshift can't do it, are there any programs that can be a security layer on top of redshift?

Comment: You can now use, out of the box, column level access control in Redshift:
[Redshift column level access control](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/03/announcing-column-level-access-control-for-amazon-redshift/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating a **View** of the columns that are permitted. Then, grant the user/group permission to use the View, but not the Table.

It would be something like:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT col1, col3 from my_table;
GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO GROUP restricted_group;
REVOKE ALL ON my_table FROM GROUP restricted_group;
```